# Debian udp port fowrding to another server does not work?

Tags: debian, iptables, udp

I have PC A (192.168.255.126, eth1) and it will receive some UDP packets, port: 51000.

Now I wish the PC A will automatically forward the UDP packets to PC B (192.168.255.127)

I have found many solutions but all of them don't work.

Solution A:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p udp --dport 51000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.127:51000
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 192.168.255.127 --dport 51000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -s 192.168.255.127 -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Solution B:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p udp --dport 51000 -j DNAT --to 192.168.255.126:51000
```

Solution C:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 51000 -j NETMAP --to 192.168.255.127
```

So what should I do?

Comment: please add something about other interfaces of PC A, if any.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure PC A does packet forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Allow forwarding on iptables:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

Let the NAT do the rest:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p udp --dport 51000 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.255.127
```